# more types plugin - display all post of post type on page

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I'm looking to display all the posts of a certain type in a page of posts. I'm using the wordpress plugin more types (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-types/) to create a custom type called pre-enjoyed.

I'd like all the posts in pre-enjoyed to be displayed when on the pre-enjoyed page.

I've never worked with custom types before and I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics of your plugin but I'll assume they are registering a custom post type.

I will also take the liberty and say you want a post based loop for your "pre-enjoyed" custom type, much like the default loop that most blogs have.

One quick method to do this is to get your theme's loop ( found in index.php or maybe loop.php) and copy and past it into a new blank php page and name that page-->  single-pre-enjoyed.php

you then  tell the loop to only grab posts from the post type pre-enjoyed using a query, for instance.

```
$query = new WP_Query( 'posts_type=pre-enjoyed');
// The Loop
```

Hope this helps, there are many ways to do this, so maybe provide some more details.